# How can I set up a WEP wifi network hosted by my PC running Windows 8, which draws its internet connection from wifi?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-8, wep

My Nintendo 3DS can connect to WPA networks, but not when running the old DS games - there it requires an open network or WEP encryption at the most. My new router doesn't support multiple SSID's unless I flash it with DD-WRT, and I don't want to do that in case it bricks the router - I asked on the DD-WRT forum, and that's apparently a remote possibility with the one I'm using! I don't want to set my main network to WEP, because that would disable 802.11n and slow the network down to 802.11g speeds.

So I'm trying to set up my PC as a wireless access point for the DS to use, but apparently Windows 8 doesn't support ad-hoc networks anymore. I tried the hostednetwork feature of netsh, but that only supports WPA, so I can't use it. I also tried Connectify, but that won't let me share my wifi connection over wifi.

Am I stuck here and need to set up the old router as a secondary AP? I tried that once but had all sorts of IP address conflicts. I think it was because I didn't understand subnet masks, so I could probably do it right this time, but I'd have to dig the old router out of wherever I put it - and it was kind of flaky to begin with, not wanting to load certain websites, so I'm not sure if it would even work anymore for Nintendo WFC!